# Chatter feed sharing

Tags: chatter-feed-tracking

I have a doubt regarding chatter feeds on a record.

For example, if User A follows user B, and user B posts something to an object (e.g. an Invention), user A does not see it in their feed. They need to be either following the object or go to the Chatter tab and then select "All Company".

If I am user B and I want user A to participate in the discussion on a specific object, how do I notify him? Or how would I "invite" him to follow the object?

Answer (score 1):

When the User B post some feed on a specific record, he can user @mention function of Chatter to mention the User A.
like @user a,
then the post will be showed on the User A's profile and also User A will get email notification.

Following is a demo about how to use @mention and #topic
http://www.salesforce.com/_app/video/chatter/help/enhance_post.jsp

Comment: yeah that's true but then we have to use @mention over again and again to share the post.

Comment: Yeah, it seems there is no standard way to do this. I have seen someone use Trigger to pass the Object feed to some specific Chatter Group for sharing.

Comment: For your information, in Spring'13, new Tasks can be added into Chatter Object feed automatically. Then you can sign someone a Task and make the discussion around this Task.

Comment: I got an idea but I don't know whether that is possible or not. As we already know, while posting a comment on a record we can use @mention to indicate the user. Can we write trigger which will extract the user from the comment and make him to follow the record explicitly. Any thought if it is doable?

Comment: The idea will work but you can't distinguish which user is really mentioned from the Body part. For example, if you have a user called User03 Test, when you mention this user, you just input the username, Salesforce will turn it into @[User03 Test], if you query the FeedItem, you can only get FeedItem:{Body=@User03 Test,.....  But if you just input @User03 Test from the Interface, you can get the same thing in the Database, like FeedItem:{Body=@User03 Test,.... Therefore, you can't really distinguish which user is really mentioned.

Comment: Also, a user can only follow 500 records, if you add the following relation in the Trigger, you should make sure it will not exceed the limit.